# The screen on the phone freezes after trying to record a video on the app

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camera, android-camera2

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    // Thread handlers for Camera2 API threads
    lateinit var handler: Handler
    lateinit var handlerThread: HandlerThread

    lateinit var backgroundHandler: Handler
    lateinit var backgroundHandlerThread: HandlerThread

    // Camera display and management objects
    lateinit var cameraManager : CameraManager
    lateinit var textureView: TextureView
    lateinit var cameraCaptureSession: CameraCaptureSession
    lateinit var cameraDevice: CameraDevice

    // Used for reading, writing, and saving
    lateinit var imageReader: ImageReader

    private lateinit var updateButton: Button

    // To be used to modify camera request settings
    lateinit var capReq: CaptureRequest.Builder

    // Variables used to manage capture request settings
    private var flashOn : Boolean = false

    private lateinit var builder : AlertDialog.Builder

    private lateinit var mediaRecorder: MediaRecorder
    private lateinit var videoFilePath: String

    private var recording = false

    private lateinit var psurface: Surface

    private lateinit var captureRequestBuilder : CaptureRequest.Builder
    private lateinit var recordingSurface : Surface
    private lateinit var previewSurface : Surface
    private lateinit var timer : Timer

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.S)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // TODO: THERE IS NO NEED TO REPEATEDLY CALL PERMS, ITS ANNOYING IN THE LOGS
        get_permissions()


        textureView = findViewById(R.id.textureView)
        textureView.surfaceTextureListener = surfaceTextureListener
        cameraManager = getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE) as CameraManager
        // Logging some stuff
        var characteristics = cameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraManager.cameraIdList[0])
        Log.d("CM INFO: RANGE", characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.CONTROL_AE_COMPENSATION_RANGE).toString())
        Log.d("CM INFO: STEP", characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.CONTROL_AE_COMPENSATION_STEP).toString())


        handlerThread = HandlerThread("videoThread")
        handlerThread.start()
        handler = Handler((handlerThread).looper)

        backgroundHandlerThread = HandlerThread("CameraVideoThread")
        backgroundHandlerThread.start()
        backgroundHandler = Handler(backgroundHandlerThread.looper)

        imageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(1080, 1920, ImageFormat.JPEG, 3)
        imageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(object: ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener {
            @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
            override fun onImageAvailable(reader: ImageReader?) {
                GlobalScope.launch {
                    writeImage(reader)

                    Log.d("Coroutine Launched", "Coroutine Launched")
                }
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Image Captured", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }

        }, handler)


        findViewById<Button>(R.id.capture).apply {
            setOnClickListener {
                Log.d("BUTTON CLICKED", "BUTTON CLICKED")
                    capReq = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE)
                    capReq.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON)
//                    capReq.set(CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE, CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE_TORCH)
                    capReq.addTarget(imageReader.surface)

                    cameraCaptureSession.capture(capReq.build(), null, null)
//                caReqV = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_RECORD)
//                capReq.addTarget(imageReader.surface)
//                cameraCaptureSession.capture(capReq.build(), null, handler)
                Log.d("Picture Taken", "Picture Taken")
            }
        }

        val recordButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.record);
        findViewById<Button>(R.id.record).apply {
            setOnClickListener {
//                if (mediaRecorder == null) {
//                    setUpMediaRecorder()
//                }
                if (recording) {
                    try {
                       mediaRecorder.stop()
                    } catch(e: IllegalStateException){
                        e.printStackTrace()
                    }

                    mediaRecorder.reset()
                    recordButton.text = "Record"
                    recording = false

                    Log.d("BUTTON CLICKED", "RECORDING STOPPED")
                } else {
                    Log.d("BUTTON CLICKED", "RECORDING STARTED")
                    recording = true
                    recordButton.text = "Recording..."

                    setUpMediaRecorder()
                    startRecording()
                    timer = Timer()
                    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(1, 10) {
                        flashOn = !flashOn

                    }
                }
            }
        }



        fun onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy()
            cameraDevice.close()
            handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)
            handlerThread.quitSafely()
        }
    }

    private val surfaceTextureListener = object: TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener {
            override fun onSurfaceTextureAvailable(
                surface: SurfaceTexture,
                width: Int,
                height: Int
            ) {
                open_camera()
            }

            override fun onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(
                surface: SurfaceTexture,
                width: Int,
                height: Int
            ) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }

            override fun onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(surface: SurfaceTexture): Boolean {
                return false
            }

            override fun onSurfaceTextureUpdated(surface: SurfaceTexture) {
                return
            }

        }

    fun startRecording() {

        var surface = Surface(textureView.surfaceTexture)
        recordingSurface = mediaRecorder.surface
        captureRequestBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_RECORD)
        captureRequestBuilder.addTarget(surface)

        captureRequestBuilder.addTarget(recordingSurface) //just added - R


        cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(listOf(surface, recordingSurface), object : CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
            override fun onConfigureFailed(session: CameraCaptureSession) {

            }

            override fun onConfigured(session: CameraCaptureSession) {
                cameraCaptureSession = session
                captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE, CaptureResult.CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO)

                if (flashOn) {
                    captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE, CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE_TORCH)
                }
                try {
                    session.setRepeatingRequest(captureRequestBuilder.build(), null, backgroundHandler)
                    mediaRecorder.start()
                } catch (e: CameraAccessException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                    Log.e(TAG, "Failed to start camera preview because it couldn't access the camera")
                } catch (e: IllegalStateException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            }
        }, backgroundHandler)
    }

//    private fun showSettings() {
//        Dialog() dialog = new Dialog(this);
//
//    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    private suspend fun writeImage(reader: ImageReader?){
        var image = reader?.acquireLatestImage()
        var buffer = image!!.planes[0].buffer
        var bytes = ByteArray(buffer.remaining())
        buffer.get(bytes)

        var file_name = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT.format(Instant.now())

        var file = File(getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), file_name + ".jpeg")
        var opStream = FileOutputStream(file)

        opStream.write(bytes)
        opStream.close()
        image.close()
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.S)
    private fun setUpMediaRecorder() {
        mediaRecorder = MediaRecorder()
        // sus
//        mediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(Surface(textureView.surfaceTexture));
        mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE)
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4)
        mediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
        mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(1920, 1080)
        mediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30);
        mediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(10_000_000)
//        mediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MPEG_4_SP)
        var file_name = SimpleDateFormat(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT.format(Instant.now())).toString()
        var file = File(getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), file_name + ".mp4")
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(file.absolutePath)

        try {
            mediaRecorder.prepare()
            recordingSurface = mediaRecorder.surface

        } catch(e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

    }


    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    fun open_camera() {
        cameraManager.openCamera(cameraManager.cameraIdList[0], object: CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
            @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.S)
            override fun onOpened(cam: CameraDevice) {
                cameraDevice = cam

                capReq = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW)

                // if flash is on
                if (flashOn) {
                    capReq.set(CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE, CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE_TORCH)
                }


                var surface = Surface(textureView.surfaceTexture)
                capReq.addTarget(surface)

                cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(listOf(surface, imageReader.surface), object:CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                    override fun onConfigured(ccs: CameraCaptureSession) {
                        cameraCaptureSession = ccs

                        ccs.setRepeatingRequest(capReq.build(), null, null)
                    }

                    override fun onConfigureFailed(session: CameraCaptureSession) {
                        return
                    }
                }, handler)
            }

            override fun onDisconnected(camera: CameraDevice) {
                return
            }

            override fun onError(camera: CameraDevice, error: Int) {
                return
            }
        }, handler)
    }

    fun get_permissions() {
        var permissionsList = mutableListOf<String>()

        if(checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            permissionsList.add(android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
        if(checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            permissionsList.add(android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
        if(checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            permissionsList.add(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)

        if (permissionsList.size > 0) {
            requestPermissions(permissionsList.toTypedArray(), 101)
        }

    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<out String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        grantResults.forEach {
            if (it!=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                get_permissions()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am working in kotlin creating an app that should take pictures and record videos. However, when I try to record a video using the record button, and then stop the recording, the screen just freezes. The video does get saved into the files on the phone, but the surface screen on the app freezes after stopping the video recording.

I've tried searching everywhere online and there just isn't any applicable info or knowledgeable people on the topic of Camera2 API. I suspect it has something to do with the surface texture after recording, but I am not entirely sure.